# TypeScript - implode a string dictionary

Tags: typescript

I'd like to have a key-value dictionary of strings (or should I use Map?), for example:

```
private queryStringParams : { [key:string] : string } = {
  "x":"y", 
  "foo":"bar"
};
```

and then implode\join\flatmap\zip it into a string such that each key\value pair is joined by a delimiter, and then all the pairs are joined by a delimiter.
For example the previous dictionary would turn into this with '&' as 1st level delimiter and '=' as 2nd level delimiter:

```
"foo=bar&x=y"
```

I can do that with arrays and loops but was thinking maybe theres a more *elegant* way to do that with TypeScript. (I'll take no as an answer as well)

Comment: You could just use jQuery's [`param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) function to do it. `jQuery.param(queryStringParams)`. There are also many, many libraries out there which serve the same function for URIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot immediately recall, but you might need the `hasOwnProperty` check depending on how complex your object hierarchy is. Nevertheless, a combination of [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Typescript template strings](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/template-strings.html), and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) can simplify this:

```
var value = Object.keys(queryStringParams)
    .map((property) => `${property}=${queryStringParams[property]}`)
    .join('&');
```

Comment: Object hierachy is just as in the example. Worked without hasOwnProperty check. Thanks.